# Match pattern anywhere in string?

Tags: regex

I want to match the following pattern:

```
Exxxx49 (where x is a digit 0-9)
```

For example, `E123449abcdefgh`, `abcdefE123449987654321` are both valid. I.e., I need to match the pattern anywhere in a string.

I am using:

```
^*E[0-9]{4}49*$
```

But it only matches `E123449`.

How can I allow any amount of characters in front or after the pattern?

Comment: What tool, what method are you using to match the pattern against the string? Anchoring depends a lot on the implementation of that.

Comment: Replace `*` with `.*`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` to search anywhere in the string.

In your case the `*` are probably not what you intended; `E[0-9]{4}49` should suffice. This will find an E, followed by four digits, followed by a 4 and a 9, anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 15):

I would go for

```
^.*E[0-9]{4}49.*$
```

EDIT:

since it fullfills all requirements state by OP.

- "[match] Exxxx49 (where x is digit 0-9)"
- "allow for any amount of characters in front or after pattern"

It will match

- `^.*` everything from, including the beginning of the line
- `E[0-9]{4}49` the requested pattern
- `.*$` everthing after the pattern, including the the end of the line

Comment: Added a capture group, and now I can extract a user id from screen scrape, bulleted list, etc.  ^.*(E[0-9]{4}49).*$  

(my pattern is actually different, but works all the same)

Answer (score 5):

Your original regex had a regex pattern syntax error at the first `*`. Fix it and change it to this:

```
.*E\d{4}49.*
```

This pattern is for matching in engines (most engines) that are anchored, like Java. Since you forgot to specify a language.

- `.*` matches any number of sequences. As it surrounds the match, this will match the entire string as long as this match is located in the string.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dT3gD8/4)!

Comment: No need to be this greedy

Answer (score 4):

Just simply use this:

```
E[0-9]{4}49
```

Comment: Your answer is in the low quality post queue. Please explain why this would answer the OPs question.

Comment: This is basically the accepted answer w/out all the fluff about why his original attempt didn't work/redundantly repeating the OP's question. The technical reason it solves it is based on how RegExs work which the OP obviously understands, and no need for Toto (any responder) to also redundantly repeat the OP's question as the (implied) explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I allow for any amount of characters in front or after pattern? but it only matches `E123449`

Use `global` flag `/E\d{4}49/g` if supported by the language

OR

Try with [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(E\d{4}49)+` that is grouped by enclosing inside parenthesis `(...)`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dT3gD8/3)

[image]